# CouchBase: Controlling which node / bucket receives data

Tags: routes, partitioning, sharding, couchbase-lite

My understanding of couchBase's clustering approach is to ensure that each node in the cluster receives an equal distribution of data. My question is if there is a way to change this and define a custom key for "intelligently" routing a document to a specific bucket in the cluster?

In my scenario, I have data which relates to a specific entity (think client-project-task-item) Across all my data; I will have enough items to require some horizontal scaling; however, each search will always relate to a given client-project-task for which the data set is only a moderate size.

I think the most efficient approach will be to partition my data by client-project-task and pre-allocate say 1000 partitions.

I understand that at a certain point this will limit my scaling capacity, but the trade off of not having to hit every partition for every search makes it one I'm willing to pay.

So is there a way to create this type of partitioning logic in CouchBase?

Alternatively - if all my data is sent across all buckets, and I define a View to query, will every query "hit" everyone of my records to check if the record is a match?

For example, I could have 400 mil total items, but by client-project-task around 100k, so it feels like a good idea to search across the 100k, not the 400mil

Any thoughts, suggestions comments welcome

Thanks; Brent